# Detached entity passed to persist error coming when creating three entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entities `CustomerDetails`, `AddressLine` and `Bankdetails`. When I am trying to create the entries in the h2 db using the `CrudRepository`, it throws an error which declares one as a detached entity.
Can anyone let me know why this error is thrown?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.ABC.AAP.Domain.Address
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:713) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

This error is thrown at the time of creating the entities.
*org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:*

```java
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    
    @Entity
    public class BankDetails {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        
    private String bank_name;
    private String account_number;
    private String ifsc_code;
    private String party_account_type;
    
        
          @OneToOne(mappedBy = "bank_details") private CustomerDetails
          customer_details;
         
    
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BankDetails other = (BankDetails) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public BankDetails(String bank_name, String account_number, String ifsc_code, String party_account_type) {
        super();
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
        this.account_number = account_number;
        this.ifsc_code = ifsc_code;
        this.party_account_type = party_account_type;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getBank_name() {
        return bank_name;
    }
    public void setBank_name(String bank_name) {
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
    }
    public String getAccount_number() {
        return account_number;
    }
    public void setAccount_number(String account_number) {
        this.account_number = account_number;
    }
    public String getIfsc_code() {
        return ifsc_code;
    }
    public void setIfsc_code(String ifsc_code) {
        this.ifsc_code = ifsc_code;
    }
    public String getParty_account_type() {
        return party_account_type;
    }
    public void setParty_account_type(String party_account_type) {
        this.party_account_type = party_account_type;
    }
}
```

2. 

```java
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    @Entity
    public class CustomerDetails {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        
        
        private String party_code;
        private String title;
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
        private String sex;
        private String nationality;
        
        
          @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          
          @JoinColumn(name="address_id",referencedColumnName = "id") private Address
          addressline;
         
        
        private String mobile_number;
        private String email_id;
        private String party_occupation;
        private String pan_number;
        private String tan_number;
        private Date date_of_birth;
        private String business_type;
        
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="bank_details_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
        private BankDetails bank_details;
    
        public CustomerDetails(String party_code, String title, String first_name, String last_name, String sex,
                String nationality, Address addressline, String mobile_number, String email_id, String party_occupation,
                String pan_number, String tan_number, Date date_of_birth, String business_type, BankDetails bank_details) {
            super();
            this.party_code = party_code;
            this.title = title;
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.last_name = last_name;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.nationality = nationality;
            this.addressline = addressline;
            this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
            this.email_id = email_id;
            this.party_occupation = party_occupation;
            this.pan_number = pan_number;
            this.tan_number = tan_number;
            this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
            this.business_type = business_type;
            this.bank_details = bank_details;
        }
    
        
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
            return result;
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            CustomerDetails other = (CustomerDetails) obj;
            if (id != other.id)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    
    
    
        public String getParty_code() {
            return party_code;
        }
    
        public void setParty_code(String party_code) {
            this.party_code = party_code;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    
        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }
    
        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }
    
        public String getLast_name() {
            return last_name;
        }
    
        public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }
    
        public String getSex() {
            return sex;
        }
    
        public void setSex(String sex) {
            this.sex = sex;
        }
    
        public String getNationality() {
            return nationality;
        }
    
        public void setNationality(String nationality) {
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }
        
        /*
         * public Address getAddressline() { return addressline; }
         * 
         * public void setAddressline(Address addressline) { this.addressline =
         * addressline; }
         */
         
    
        public String getMobile_number() {
            return mobile_number;
        }
    
        public void setMobile_number(String mobile_number) {
            this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
        }
    
        public String getEmail_id() {
            return email_id;
        }
    
        public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
            this.email_id = email_id;
        }
    
        public String getParty_occupation() {
            return party_occupation;
        }
    
        public void setParty_occupation(String party_occupation) {
            this.party_occupation = party_occupation;
        }
    
        public String getPan_number() {
            return pan_number;
        }
    
        public void setPan_number(String pan_number) {
            this.pan_number = pan_number;
        }
    
        public String getTan_number() {
            return tan_number;
        }
    
        public void setTan_number(String tan_number) {
            this.tan_number = tan_number;
        }
    
        public Date getDate_of_birth() {
            return date_of_birth;
        }
    
        public void setDate_of_birth(Date date_of_birth) {
            this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
        }
    
        public String getBusiness_type() {
            return business_type;
        }
    
        public void setBusiness_type(String business_type) {
            this.business_type = business_type;
        }
    
        public BankDetails getBank_details() {
            return bank_details;
        }
    
        public void setBank_details(BankDetails bank_details) {
            this.bank_details = bank_details;
        }
}
```

3. 

```java
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    
    @Entity
    public class Address {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        
        
          @OneToOne(mappedBy = "addressline") private CustomerDetails customer_details;
         
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Address other = (Address) obj;
            if (id != other.id)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        private String address1;
        private String address2;
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private String country;
        private String pincode;
        
        
        
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public Address(String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String country, String pincode) {
            super();
            this.address1 = address1;
            this.address2 = address2;
            this.city = city;
            this.state = state;
            this.country = country;
            this.pincode = pincode;
        }
        public String getAddress1() {
            return address1;
        }
        public void setAddress1(String address1) {
            this.address1 = address1;
        }
        public String getAddress2() {
            return address2;
        }
        public void setAddress2(String address2) {
            this.address2 = address2;
        }
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }
        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }
        public String getPincode() {
            return pincode;
        }
        public void setPincode(String pincode) {
            this.pincode = pincode;
        }
}
```

** Issue resolved : Issue was due to the cascade type during the creation of entries . **I was using CascadeType.ALL but when changed to CascadeType.MERGE then it was resolved .**

Comment: Can you please share the creation and persistence code for these entities?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in Entity, if you are add ID by yourself, hibernate think that this entity already in DB and for him it is detached entity.

Tip: try do not use GenerationType.AUTO, instead a better approach using SEQUENCE or IDENTITY.

AUTO - we are delegating ID creation strategy to persistence provider which is not always the best approach.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html more about strategies.